# Steps to create a mono repo with sitecore jss starter template

Tags: jss, docker, xm-cloud, sxa-jss, jss-rendering-sdk

I am using [this template](https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head) to create my sitecore solution. I am planning to convert the sxastarter folder into a monorepo. So the folder structure will be something similar to this.

[image]

Obviously my sitecore deploy command is failing since its looking the nextjs project inside sxastarter folder but now it has been moved to sxastarter/site.
Is this a possible monorepo approach with jss starter?.
If so what are the other files that I need to change in order to properly run sitecore deployment commands

Comment: you can try to change mapping here: https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head/blob/main/docker-compose.override.yml#L22 , so your rendering image will be built from other folder